# Python~JSON error → json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, discord, discord.py

I was working on my discord bot and found a api(named [numapi](https://numbersapi.com/)) which i want to use, i made a prototype in my pc which was ↓↓↓↓ and it worked fine.

```py
import requests
import json

def numapi(no):
    response = requests.get(f'http://numbersapi.com/{no}?json')
    #print(response.json())
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    num = json_data['text']
    return(num)

while True:
    inc = input('enter ')
```

But when i copied the same thing in my discord bot then it was not working. The code and error are as follows :-

> code

```py
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()

def numapi(no):
    #http://numbersapi.com/#505/year
    response = requests.get(f'http://numbersapi.com/{no}?json')
    #print(response.json())
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    num = json_data['text']
    return(num)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('$fact'):
        number = message.content.split('$fact', 1)[1]
        fact = numapi(number)
        #await message.channel.send(number)
        await message.channel.send(fact)

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

> error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 291, in on_message
    fact = numapi(number)
  File "main.py", line 89, in numapi
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

pls help me slove this

Comment: check what `number` is. Also why do you commented `response.json()` and use `json.loads()` instead?

Comment: `json.loads()` assumes that the data is encoded. Probably you're receiving a bytes string. Try `response.text.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: One more thing. `number = message.content.split('$fact', 1)[1]` This assumes that there are no spaces after `$fact`. So try `fact = numapi(int(number.strip()))`

Comment: @buran i check everything, its all fine. and i commented that because i was just seeing what all thing are there in that json and i used `json.loads()` to import that json

Comment: `requests.Response.json()` is a convenience method you can just `json_data = response.json()`.  What do you get when you `print(repr(number))`?

Comment: So, it wasn't "all fine" after all

Comment: Alright I have submitted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads()` assumes that the data is decoded. Probably you're receiving a bytes string. Try `response.text.decode('utf-8')`.